# Error : Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

This is my program for uploading an image:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string car_model = TextBox1.Text;
    string car_brand = TextBox2.Text;
    string car_type = TextBox3.Text;
    int dist_travel = int.Parse(TextBox4.Text);
    int mileage = int.Parse(TextBox5.Text);
    string car_condition = TextBox6.Text;
    string car_owner = TextBox7.Text;
    string car_color = TextBox8.Text;
    int car_price = int.Parse(TextBox9.Text);

    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        byte[] fdata = FileUpload1.FileBytes;

        string con_string = @"data source=(local);initial catalog=Automobile;integrated security=true";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = con_string;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into vehicle_details values ('" + car_model + "','" + car_type + "','" + dist_travel + "','" + mileage + "','" + car_condition + "','" + car_owner + "','" + car_color + "','" + fdata + "','" + car_price + "')";
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

then it throws the following error:

> Implicit conversion from data type `varchar` to `varbinary(max)` is not allowed. Use the `CONVERT` function to run this query.

And structure of database is  car_model varchar, car_type varchar, dist_travel int, mileage int,car_condition varchar, car_owner varchar, car_color varchar, fdata varbinary(MAX), car_price varchar

Comment: You need to **(a)** show us what your table structure is (column names and datatypes), and **(b)** you should be using a **parametrized query** to avoid SQL injection!

Comment: What is your database structure Which of the columns is of varbinary type? Won't it be better to specify the columns by name? (it will make the code more robust for possible schema changes). What is not obvious on the error message?

Comment: You may have declared fdata as byte[] but

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have declared fdata as byte[] but the section of code that reads

```
... + "','" + fdata + "','" + ....
```

is forcing it into a string so that it can be part of the command text

You're going to have to parameterise the query